# Can I use oak trees for Birkat Ilanot

Tags: blessing

I live where it's Iyar, April 28 and the few fruit trees I know which are apple haven't yet blossomed.

But oak are plentiful and have long bloomed.
I didn't find an answer in Yalkut Yosef or Yechave Daat however it seems to me because if I processed the acorns into edible meal the berakhah would be haEtz therefore they are are fit for the berakhah.

Comment: @nissim nanach just curious- what's your basis that if you process acorns to make them edible then they would be haEtz? I'm not saying you're wrong- I'm not sure myself- but I 'm curious if you have a source. Plenty of things which grow on trees are shehakol since it's not normal to eat them (the Mishna berurah quoting Chaye adam and others, say the bracha on berries from ilanei srak is shehakol, since they're not grown for the berries and it's not considered a normal type of food. )

Comment: @Binyomin https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Brachot_On_Foods_That_Start_With_The_Letter_A#cite_ref-1

Comment: RFפ? [charac15]

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5954/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37621/759

Comment: Nissim, it's unlikely you'll find a precise definition of 'fruit' here since no one knows for sure why the general practice is to only use fruit trees. Maybe if we had the reason we could figure out what's included in 'fruit'.

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks for that source. I'm curious if any Ashkenazi poskim discuss it (Do the Sephardim take on like the Mishna berura etc. that fruit from ilanei srak  is shehakol?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a bracha for blooming non-fruit trees?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14273/is-there-a-bracha-for-blooming-non-fruit-trees)

Comment: @user15464 The other question is limited to non-fruit trees. This question is about whether oak trees count as fruit trees or not

Comment: BTW Next day, Apr 29 I recited over some serviceberry trees that I had forgotten about; they're early blooming.

Comment: @Double_AA Where would one look to? The oldest source is only the Tanna's mention in Berakhot 43b?  NLA"D the lashon of the bracha seems it should allow not just fruit trees: "Beriyot tovot we'ilanot tovot."